# Normal closure in groups

Tags: group-theory

For instance, say $G = \langle x , y \ | \ x^{12}y=yx^{18} \rangle$. I want to know what is the [normal closure](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup_generated_by_a_subset) of $y$ in $G$.

In general, what are the standard approaches to compute the normal closure of a subset of a finitely presented group? Are there algorithms?

Comment: In general, the normal closure will not be finitely generated. In what sense do you want to "know" it?

Comment: It is f.g. here.

Comment: Well, the question is *in general*...

Comment: @Mariano: If you know many senses, please let me know.

Answer (score 13):

You can compute the normal closure by computing the quotient, and then considering the kernel of the quotient homomorphism.

For the example you gave, let $N$ be the normal closure of $y$ in $G$.  Then $G/N$ has presentation
$$
\langle x,y \mid x^{12}y = yx^{18},y=1\rangle
$$
This presentation reduces to $\langle x \mid x^{12} = x^{18}\rangle$, which is the same as $\langle x \mid x^6 = 1\rangle$.

Thus $G/N$ is a cyclic group of order 6, and $N$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $G\to G/N$. In particular, the normal closure of $y$ consists of all words for which the total power of $x$ is a multiple of 6.